# Interpolate underwater quality data with QGIS as with Surfer with Kriging method

Tags: qgis, interpolation, kriging, surfer

I'm trying to interpolate conductivity data form a coastal area about 4-6 square km from a series of 10-20 probe wells more or less equally distributed.

I have access to a licensed Surfer and to QGIS 3.16. My first intention was to emulate the results from the prior on the later using the interpolation tools 'Ordinary Kriging' and 'Simple Kriging' in order to generate some interpolated rasters of conductivity at several depths.

I had no previous knowledge about the Kriging method. So I tried to take the parameters resulting from the Kriging method calculated on Surfer and apply them directly on QGIS. But that proved a not so easy task and failed.

Then tried to play around with the QGIS tools parameters intending to achieve some coherent results and... failed again. I managed to found a set of parameters that gave a similar result for some depths but gave a raster totally different for other depths.

Note that I'm not intending to make a course on hydrogeology, just realise if QGIS could be a substitute of Surfer for this task. So, is this feasible? Could QGIS, ArcMap or another non-specialized GIS tool make some Kriging interpolations that show results similar to those of Surfer?

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask why you don’t want to just use Surfer? If it’s a licensing issue, Golden Software also offers Surfer on a monthly subscription basis ($100/mo) so you could just use it for a month whenever you have projects that need it. Golden Software also offers student and academic pricing, if that applies.

You could get similar results with QGIS or ArcGIS, both offer Kriging interpolation. However, like you found, it probably won’t be the exact same as Surfer. It possibly could be the data itself, not the interpolation that’s different though (if it’s acceptable for some depths, but not others – it could be the data distribution for the particular depths that causes the differences). Or perhaps it’s the variograms used by Kriging that are different. I do not know what variograms QGIS or ArcGIS uses with their Kriging interpolation by default. Surfer is known for its gridding (interpolation) algorithms and contouring options, so if you want it the same as Surfer’s results, you might want to just use Surfer.

Comment: Hi Kari. and thanks for your answer. In fact the main motive for using QGis is corporate/administrative culture. We are trying to rely mainly on free software options. I suspect, as you comment, that Surfer does 'something more' previously to interpolate the data and probably adjusts the variogram or some other parameters automatically to the data for every depth. I could try to automate it on QGis if I knew the maths involved, but now that I have read some essays on kriging I'm realizing that task doesn't seem that easy either.